Confluent Kafka admin client not throwing exception
When initializing a connection to a none existent kafka broker the client is sending error to stdout but when I add a try block its not throwing an exception. In the documentation the admin client should raise KafkaException.
Confluent Kafka documentation
confluent-kafka==2.2.0
%3|1729693737.667|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:ssl://kafka.test-123.com:443/bootstrap]: ssl://kafka.test-123.com:443/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka.test-123.com:443': No such host is known.  (after 27ms in state CONNECT)

from confluent_kafka import admin, KafkaException, KafkaError

KAFKA_BROKER = "kafka.test-123.com:443"

KAFKA_ADMIN_CONFIG = {
        'bootstrap.servers':KAFKA_BROKER,
        'security.protocol':'SSL',
        }

try:
    admin.AdminClient(KAFKA_ADMIN_CONFIG)
except (KafkaException, KafkaError) as e:
    print("failed")

